# Conditional Probability : Total probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be set of mutually exclusive events of which one necessarily occurs (i.e. union of $H_1$ and $H_2$ is the sample space). A is any event that can occur in conjunction with some $H_i$. So it is well known that
$P(A)=P(A\mid H_1)\cdot P(H_1)+P(A\mid H_2)\cdot P(H_2)$. But what will be an upper bound on this probability $P(A)$? I read it somewhere that we can consider $P(A)\leq P(A\mid H_1)+P(\overline{H}_1)$ where $H_2=\overline{H}_1$. What is the intuition behind it?

Comment: Terminology note: If you have two mutually exclusive (i.e. disjoint) events, one of which must occur, then those two are called _complementary events_.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A)=&~\mathsf P(A\mid H_1)\,\mathsf P(H_1)+\mathsf P(A\mid \overline{H_1})\,\mathsf P(\overline{H_1})&\text{since: }&\text{Law of Total Probability}
\\[1ex] \le&~ \mathsf P(A\mid H_1)+\mathsf P(A\mid \overline{H_1})\,\mathsf P(\overline{H_1}) & \text{since: }&\mathsf P(H_1)\le 1\\[1ex] \le&~ \mathsf P(A\mid H_1)+\mathsf P(\overline{H_1}) & \text{since: }&\mathsf P(A\mid \overline{H_1})\le 1 \\[1ex]&&&\blacksquare\end{align}$$

Comment: But  $P(H_1) \leq 1$  then $P(\overline{H_1}) \geq 0$ . So how can we write it as $P(A|H_1)+P(\overline{H_1})$ ? The term after '+' must be 0 right ?

Comment: Maximum value that $P(H_1)$ can attain is 1. But since $H_2$ and $H_1$ are mutually exclusive then if one of the event definitely occurs then other should'nt occur as per the law of probability distribution

Comment: Well, we could continue because $0\leq \mathsf P(\text{anything})\leq 1$, and we are looking for *upper bounds*; but there is such a thing as going too far.$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A)\leq &~ \mathsf P(A\mid H_1)+1 \\ \leq&~ 2\end{align}$$Which is pointlessly true.

Comment: We're not looking for $\mathsf P(A)$ when $\mathsf P(H_1)$ is maximum, we're just looking for some upper bound on $\mathsf P(A)$.

Comment: But A is definitely dependent on $H_1$. I mean that can there be an intuitive explanation as to why are we  estimating it  in this fashion ?

Comment: For the assumption made above that $P(A)\leq 2$, you consider that any probability is less than 1 but if 2 events are there is the sample space then it gets subjected to $\Sigma $Pr(each event)=1 as well .